# pandas.read_sql 'Invalid Cursor state'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

i have a flask python app which runs under Apache (using mod_wsgi). A particular URL will cause the app to query a microsoft database using pandas and ceODBC.

```
ret = pandas.read_sql(sql_str, self._connection)
```

the sql above is a very basic 'select' on a single table, no joins what so ever.
During development this is not a problem (likely because Flask is single threaded).
However at run time, the app runs under Apache and i have a particular page that issues 6 simultaneous calls to the same URL.  Frequently this causes the following exception:

```
  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1046, in read_sql
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1041, in execute
    raise_with_traceback(ex)
  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1030, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql....
```

And at that time i think the state becomes bad, so subsequent calls will lead to exceptions like these:

```
File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 421, in read_sql
    coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates)
  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1048, in read_sql
    data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1061, in _fetchall_as_list
    result = cur.fetchall()
DatabaseError: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state

  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 421, in read_sql
    coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates)
  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1048, in read_sql
    data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
  File "C:\proj\pd_test\py_virt_env\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1061, in _fetchall_as_list
    result = cur.fetchall()
DatabaseError: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Function sequence error
```

Is this a multi-threaded issue?  Can pandas.read_sql handle multiple simultaneous reads  agains the same connection?  maybe the question is whether it uses the same cursor or a different cursor for each read?  The driver i am using is ceODBC

Comment: I wonder if using an sqlalchemy engine would get around this.

Comment: i was able to resolve by opening/closing a connection each time i need to execute the query, but i'm not sure i like that solution.  i went wit ceODBC because i find it faster than sqlAlchemy and pyOdbc

Comment: That's what unsuspected. You definitely have to close out connections and cursors. That's why I like sqlalchemy. Takes care of that for you.

Comment: In principle, only sqlalchemy engines are supported in pandas for specifying the connection to a database, see the docstring for the `con` argument: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql

Comment: ok..perhaps i'll put the solution i found as an answer for those that may be encountering the same issue and are not using sqlAlchemy.  I wasn't aware that sqlAlchemy opens and closes connection when executing queries.  I suppose it is one way of minimizing issues with cursor state, but seems odd having come from a java/.net world where you often open a connection and keep it open for the duration of the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by opening/closing a connection each time i need to execute a query.

```
with ceODBC.connect(self.CONNECT_STR) as conn:
    result = pandas.read_sql(sql, conn)
```